# Why is image_proc only show the upper left half of my image?

Tags: ros, image, image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, 
I am currently publishing an image which is 1024x1024 pixels and I am trying to rectify it using image_proc. The output of my /camera/camera_info is:

**header: 

seq: 3692

stamp: 

secs: 1405337388

nsecs: 154563950

frame_id: camera

height: 1024

width: 1024

distortion_model: plumb_bob

D: [-0.183149270183746, 0.139143255380374, 0.00225718725189143, 0.00131346587970189, 0.0]

K: [1189.58587069262, 0.0, 501.625685647322, 0.0, 1188.97100074168, 550.474655398214, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

R: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

P: [1151.62145996094, 0.0, 501.542604357335, 0.0, 0.0, 1150.24182128906, 553.703494449055, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]

binning_x: 2

binning_y: 2

roi: 

x_offset: 0

y_offset: 0

height: 0

width: 0

do_rectify: True**

While the header of the output of /camera/image_raw is:
**header: 

seq: 7082

stamp: 

secs: 1405337872

nsecs: 724561256

frame_id: camera

height: 1024

width: 1024

encoding: mono8

is_bigendian: 0

step: 1024**

So the problem is that, when I run **$ROS_NAMESPACE=camera image_proc image_proc**  I get images to be published at /camera/image_rect that have the following header: 


**header: 

seq: 20 

stamp: 

secs: 1405338132

nsecs: 447977005

frame_id: camera

height: 512

width: 512

encoding: mono8 

is_bigendian: 0 

step: 512**

I can see with image_view that the image in the rectified version is only the 512x512 upper left of the original 1024x1024 image_raw
Does anyone know why image_proc is only grabbing only the first upper 512x512 pixels of my image? It seems to me to be some kind of ROI problem, but I cannot see where...

Thanks in advance,
Pedro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186499/why-is-image_proc-only-show-the-upper-left-half-of-my-image?/) by [PedroGusmao](https://answers.ros.org/users/7556/pedrogusmao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2014-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I think I have found the answer.

The problem is how to treat the "pixel binning" fields of the Camera Info Messages.
The driver I am using actually publishes that the camera has already processed the original image and has used a 2x2 pixel binning to reduce the size of the image alongo with the new (reduced) dimension of the image.
The package image_proc however, uses that information once again to generate an empty matrix for the rectified image.
i.e.:
My camera driver uses Format7 Video Mode 0 to produce a 1024x1024 image (after binning its original 2048x2048 using 2x2 bins).

The problem is that it also publishes the binning information, so

binning_x: 2 
binning_y: 2

Which causes some problems for image_proc for it tries to generate a (1024/2)x(1024/2) empty matrix which will be partially filled up with the rectified frame...

See ya

---

Originally posted by [PedroGusmao](https://answers.ros.org/users/7556/pedrogusmao/) with karma: 66 on 2014-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0